# how to move an image infinitely across canvas JS, HTML

Tags: javascript, image, loops, canvas

So I have this school project where we are supposed to create an animation in HTML canvas using javascript. However we only really touched on basic DOM manipulation, and how the canvas works. So I'm stumped for the idea I submitted.

Basically I have a background image and ontop of that a transparent "surface" image which is the trees and road that I want to loop infinitely to the left to create the effect that the car sprite is moving. I'm not sure how to achieve this, every time I try to draw the image nothing appears, and I have no idea how to go about creating the loop effect either.

Comment: Maybe just try to implement the DVD screen that never hits the corner.

Comment: yeah you're probably right I thought it would be easy to figure out but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I usually try to push myself but maybe this time I should stay within my limits LOL

Comment: Babysteps ;) You'll learn how to break down complicated things into small tasks sooner or later.

Comment: Oh and you might want to look into modulo. You can use it to calculate the repeating texture coordinates.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?